# mixing google maps api v2 and v3 possible?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

[One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336626/get-localsearch-in-maps-v2-api-to-search-a-default-value-on-load) linked an [interesting example of mixing API v2 and v3!](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#localsearch). Look at the code:

```
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

    // Create and Center a Map
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

    // bind a search control to the map, suppress result list
    map.addControl(new google.maps.LocalSearch(), new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_RIGHT, new GSize(10,20)));
  }
}
GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

The map is apparently in v2 but the code `new google.maps.LocalSearch()` is v3!

**How is this possible?**

Maybe it's not really API v3. I thought it could be deprecated [Local Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/devguide.html) that worked within [API v2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html), but it is not: in this API the object is `google.search.localSearch` while here it is `google.maps.localsearch` ... I'm totaly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example only uses v2, not v3 at all. The v2 API does optionally expose everything under `google.maps` (for example `google.maps.GeoXml`) – most people just use the 'G' naming though.

There's also a difference between `google.search.LocalSearch` (which lets you query Google for local search results) and `google.maps.LocalSearch` (which is a v2 control). Since both APIs are deprecated, I'd avoid both!